# Audio not working on upgrading to Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: drivers, sound, updates, 15.04

I have upgraded ubuntu from previous version to latest 15.04 on my desktop, 32-bit(os). I found that my audio files are not giving sound while playing, I tested online video from youtube, even they are not giving sound.

I searched on internet, only found [this](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/265911) link which is not understandable for me.

Please help me out in getting my desktop sound back.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by using this command in a terminal:

```
alsamixer
```

When the program is started, increase the level for all bars.

Comment: even increasing levels of all the bars.. i am not able to here sound???